# Stack Overflow (main site) logo renders incorrectly on Safari Version 8.0.8 (10600.8.9)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, logo

I'm on a mid 2014 retina [MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) and am browsing with [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) version 8.0.8 (10600.8.9). The logo appears to not render correctly. Note the problem with the `a`:

[image: Stack Overflow logo]

The logo looks fine on Chrome version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) and Firefox version 40.0.3, however.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using the exact same Safari version. The logo itself seems to be an [SVG sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on 8.0.7 (10600.7.12). Zooming in even just a tad causes it to render correctly, but at 100% zoom I see the above.

Comment: I can see the same artifact in Safari 9.0 (11601.1.56) (El Cap version) I have to zoom twice before the artifact goes away.

Comment: Reproduce Safari 9, worth noting that meta logo is unaffected.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue using Safari 9 (11601.1.56) on a non-retina MBP. Just in case you were wondering if the issue was retina-only.

Comment: I must ask, how did you notice such a minor discrepancy?

Comment: You can hardly miss it. It's like a hot pixel on your screen, always there, always taunting you.

Comment: I'm also able to reproduce this, I have the same specs as royhowie. Cannot unsee... .

Comment: I can reproduce this on Safari 8.0.8 on a Mac Mini with a non-retina Dell monitor.

Comment: I too can replicate the issue on Safari Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18) on a Mac Book Pro retina

Comment: Nice catch! And reproducible on Safari 10600.8.9 on a MBP retina.

Comment: Same here, it appears to be an SVG rendering bug.

Comment: ... and reproducible on Safari 8.0.5 on a MacBook Air running OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Instead of telling Stack Exchange, you might consider telling Apple so this might get fixed and all of you can stop nagging about it.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Safari 9.1 (11601.5.17.1)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good news! We have finally completed execution of our long-term plan to resolve this issue. I know it's been a long time, and really the effort that went into this is simply immeasurable. Really, you just can't even imagine how much we put into resolving this Safari bug.

If you're curious on the details of our super elaborate plan, the detailed version is:
"Wait for Apple to fix their stuff"

I'm glad to report, the team of 0 people dedicated to this have finally achieved success.

I kid, but really: there's very little we can do with these other than file a bug. And on third-party bugs, several users chiming in has more weight than 1 of us doing it.